# Tikz draw inside "axis" environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw additional lines inside a plot. For example take,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = -1:1, samples = 500]
    \addplot[color = red]  {4-rad(acos(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will produce a nice graph. Now when I try to add (say equally distributed) ticks on the y-axis, and draw small lines horizontally into the graph, and then down to the x-axis like this:
[image]

it simple does not work: any

```
 \draw
```

outside the axis environment will no longer paint over the axis, but somewhere else. Example:

```
 \foreach \y in {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2} \draw (-2pt, \y) -- (2pt, \y) ;
```

will not plot the ticks over the "axis" y-axis. And if I put the same command (replacing \y by y) inside the axis, I get

ERROR: Missing control sequence inserted.

--- TeX said ---

\inaccessible
\draw (-2pt, y) -- (+2pt, y) ;

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` for the lines. See the manual (p.547 v.1.18.1).

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
  domain=-1:1,samples=500,
  xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=0,
  ytick={0,0.5,...,4},
]
\addplot[color = red] {4-rad(acos(x))};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,1.5,...,3.5}
{ 
  \addplot[mark=none,gray,very thin] coordinates {(-1.5,#1) (cos(deg(4-#1)),#1) (cos(deg(4-#1)),0)}; 
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]